# Commitment fulfilled seems to act erratic on area 51

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

I have previously received commitment fulfilled when I had submitted 10 questions or answers fulfil the commitment. However, on a current commitment I have 13 and have not been released. Is this an automatic process, or something manual? What are the exact criteria?

Comment: This is interesting for me, I committed to a site but when I arrived, most of my questions had already been asked .. and most of the questions I could answer had already been answered. So I'm kind of hunting around for opportunities to participate, and I'm worried that I might not reach 'the bar'.

Comment: Maybe participation should rather/also be measured on views and days on the site?

Answer (score 5):

The commitment isn't fulfilled until about a day after the site enters public beta.  This is because it's especially important for people who committed to the site to be on at the beginning of the public beta.

**Edit**

The other criteria is that you post 10 questions or answers.

Comment: "You'll also receive a little boost if you earned the beta badge", you mean rep on area51?

Comment: I'm a little confused on that part, if I ask 5 and answer 5 have I met that end of the criteria?

Comment: Well. in a previous private betas, this was not the case

Comment: @txwikinger correct, but it seemed wrong so we changed it

Comment: Well, it only restricts without effect. If someone has already fulfilled the commitment it does not matter what they do for the days they are bound. On the other hand, if they care, they stick around and do things in either case. Seems a lame duck rule to me

Comment: @txwikinger it seemed wrong to send you an email saying "thanks! you've fulfilled your commitment" on the second day of the private beta...so now we wait until it's been in beta at least 8 days

Comment: @David Fuller: What is wrong by saying: "Thanks your fulfilled your minimum commitment. We and the community would be grateful if you could continue such great support throughout the beta of this site. Only the participation of committed users can make this site a success in the long run".

Comment: "The other criteria is that you post 10 questions or answers." Does that mean that the sum of your amount of questions and answers should be 10, or that you have to post 10 questions/10 answers?