# Did the requirements for fulfilling beta commitments change?

Tags: support, commitment-fulfillment

Today a user [commented](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/commitment-indicator#comment8539_1982) on an Area51 post of mine about [the 10 posts (questions +  answers) required to fulfill a commitment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57878/154510).  He got the Beta badge on Poker and his Area 51 profile shows the commitment fulfilled, but he's only made 8 posts on that site.  Have the requirements changed?  If not, is it perhaps counting deleted posts or something?

Comment: I've posted six answers and a question on [Sports](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/12) and that was enough. No deleted posts either.

Comment: There was a fellow who blasted the Biblical Hermeneutics site with 10 quick questions.  (Not complaining about that; most were good.)  When someone asked why he had done that, he said he wanted to fulfill his commitment so that he could commit somewhere else.  I checked back with his Area 51 profile once in a while for several months and the commitment stuck.  Now I see that it's cleared.   All of which to say, it seems, um, inconsistent.

Comment: @JonEricson what do you mean by "Now I see that it's cleared."? The software reversed his previously fulfilled commitment after having first indicated for several months that he *had* fulfilled his commitment?

Comment: @CopyrightX: I mean: the commitment was not cleared for a long time and then it was.  And I checked again and it still is cleared.  I can't tell if he was able to commit to anything else though...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, the requirements can be slightly lower if you're an active participant during the *private* beta. Asking and answering are still the quickest / easiest way to fulfill commitment though, regardless of when you do it.

Comment: Is cancelling Meta bounties a thing now? :P

Comment: It is if I'm just answering a support question. You can probably find something more useful to do with the meta rep.

Comment: So I participated in Network Engineering during its _private_ beta with two questions (one I deleted voluntarily as it was fast on its way to being closed by others) and two answers. Since it went public I posted several other answers so that my NE profile currently shows I've posted 1 question and 9 answers. That was >24 hours ago, and still my area51 profile shows zero fulfilled commitments. Do I need to contribute more to NE to fulfill my commitment there? Or do I need to wait awhile before my profile shows the fulfilled commitment? I don't understand how this commitment fulfillment works.

Comment: I read "Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began." at http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#commitment and wonder if anyone can elaborate on when I'll "...be able to re-use the commitment" I foolishly invested in NE. Six months would be painful...

Comment: @CopyrightX: there is a reputation requirement as well; you need to actually post stuff folks find *useful*.

Comment: Details? Maybe in a FAQ somewhere? Rather than scattered all over the place? Posting something _useful_ in a group of hundreds of professional L2/L3 Network Engineers is going to be essentially impossible for someone who is not a professional L2/L3 Network Engineer. SE created a closed-group site for this crowd without advance labeling as such. Community Proposal description reads, "Beta Q&A site for network engineers." I'm a network engineer. Just not a professional one. Better description would have been, "Beta Q&A site for L2/L3 professional Network Engineers." I'd never have committed.

Comment: @CopyrightX: I'm pretty sure the lack of clear and visible documentation on this is *by-design* - the intent isn't to give folks a bare minimum threshold to try and scrape by, it's to encourage them to participate on the new site they've committed to participating on. I'll note that in your specific case, most of what you've written hasn't received any votes - so as far as the system is concerned, it's not really doing much. As far as NE knowledge goes, if you're having trouble contributing by answering, why not post a few questions of your own?

Comment: Did you check the two questions I did post? Closed or deleted on the way to closure because they were deemed off-topic. Seems that **Real Network Engineers** don't use Linksys gear. That stuff is _contemptible_! (Never mind that the name is owned by Cisco.) So the other requirement for contributing _useful_ stuff there is that I own or have access to Cisco routers. Again, woulda been nice to see that in the Community Proposal description before I committed.

Comment: Bottom line, if committing _actually_ means something _more_ than what one explicitly agrees to with, "I commit to participate actively in Community X for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and _to ask or answer at least ten questions_.", then for Pete's sake, that oughta be explicitly stated. Committing to something nebulous (while under the false impression that commitment requirements are explicitly stated in a written contract) is a near-guarantee of disappointment and disillusionment. I could just join the Scientologists if I wanted that.

Comment: From [the Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq): *If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began.* **Nowhere** does it state that 10 posts will immediately satisfy a commitment. To be perfectly honest, if you're signing on to a site without any real interest in the topic beyond doing the bare minimum to get in and get out, we'd rather you didn't bother, @CopyrightX.

Comment: So implement an "uncommit" option as so many others have asked for. This proposal was a poor fit for me from Day 1 because the description was fundamentally misleading. Making the requirements for fulfilling a commitment as vague as this only aggravates the problem. Unless you can see something that I cannot see, this experience exposes a fundamental flaw in the software design: how to deal with minorities who (through no fault of their own) are unable to commit in ways that are _useful_ to the majority.

Comment: Do questions/answers on the meta site count towards commitment?

Answer (score -1):

You should count all non-CW (non-community wiki) posts including questions and answers on both of the main and meta sites (including deleted once). However it's not always achieved by posting exact 10 posts as mentioned [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1982/61861), since the exact logic of achieving commitment fulfilment is publicly not shared not, however it's most likely between 8-10 posts.

In my case I had 7 answers & 1 question on the main site and 1 answer on meta site with rep of 300 (9 posts in total, not 10). This was enough of achieving fulfilled commitment for. So most likely participating during private beta could make the difference.

Here are some hints found in [*Area51 FAQ*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) section in terms of fulfilling commitment:

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering **a few questions**, you'll be able to commit to another site. **If you are very active**, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began.