# What does "follow through on your commitment" actually mean?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51, private-beta

I am having trouble ascertaining *exactly* what the commitment means, when referring to the **ten questions/answers**:

- Do they have to be in *private* beta, or does *public* beta count as well?
- Can the posting of the questions and answers straddle the private and public betas?
- Is it ten questions, or ten answers or is a mixture of both acceptable?

From Area 51's FAQ:

> After a proposal enters the beta phase, you earn the most reputation when you follow through on your commitment or a user you referred follows through on theirs. Even better, that extra reputation doesn't count towards your maximum reputation per day:
>
> Follow through on your commitment +50

This does not explain the conditions, only that the commitment must be fulfilled. So, what exactly is the commitment? To look further, I actually committed to a proposed site...

From the committed dialog:

> I commit to participate actively in ***** for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

From the `to ask or answer at least ten questions` I would assume that the answer to my third point is that a mix is acceptable. However, the private/public beta issue is still not clear in my mind, as the `especially` seems to imply that it is a *desirable*, but not a *condition*.

Looking at [How to “follow through” on an area51 proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103294/how-to-follow-through-on-an-area51-proposal), the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103294/how-to-follow-through-on-an-area51-proposal#answer-103295) states:

> If you weren't active enough during the private beta, you will need to post at least 10 questions or answers to fulfill your commitment.

Which implies that the questions/answers can straddle private and beta.

However, the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/commitment-fulfilled-seems-to-act-erratic-on-area-51/57878#57878) to [Commitment fulfilled seems to act erratic on area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/commitment-fulfilled-seems-to-act-erratic-on-area-51), appears to *contradict* the above (the comments to the answer seem to confuse matters even further). The answer states:

> The commitment isn't fulfilled until about a day after the site enters public beta.

Which implies that the commitment *has* to be during private, and hence, the questions/answers need to be posted in private.

I am starting assume that the ten questions and/or answers need to be answered in the private beta only, as at that stage I had only answered/asked six in total, on Hardware Recommendations, and then four more in public, but my +50 reputation on Area 51 never materialised. Is there a period of time one has to wait for the ten questions/answers to be recognised?

Unfortunately, my situation has been complicated by one of my answers being deleted, for being (understandably) more of a support nature, rather than a recommendation.

I will obviously continue to contribute to SE HW Recommendations, as I find the site interesting, but I am at a bit of a loss w.r.t. the +50 points (which, TBH, I didn't even know about until two days ago, so I'm not too fussed about them).

Comment: relevant, but old: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/commitment-indicator

Comment: @sumelic - Thanks. So, back then, in 2011, it was vague then, and, to my mind, it still is. It doesn't seem as if the [FAQ was properly updated](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/how-does-the-system-determine-when-you-have-fulfilled-a-commitment#comment-4165). It does seem a bit daft that one has to read through a faq and three questions on meta, and four on Area 51 Discussions in order to find the answer. It should be noted, succinctly, in one place.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a definitive answer, but I recently was awarded 50 rep on Area 51 after having 7 upvoted answers, 2 upvoted questions, and 600 rep even on the committed site.  I'm guessing it's the 600 rep that did it but there might be some other stuff involved too.

Comment: @brandaemon - So you only had _nine_ posts? Not ten? That is strange... Did you have ten at any point in time, and one was (subsequently) deleted?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I only ever had nine. That's why think it was the 600 rep. Maybe edits of some kind count?  Maybe questions scored 10+ count double?  Who knows?